Is my recollection of a proof of Menger’s theorem (two-point form) valid?
I am trying to learn the proof of the following theorem:

Theorem (Menger’s Theorem, two-point form): If $G$ is a graph, $a, b$ are non-adjacent vertices in $G$, then there exist $k$ independent $a$-$b$ edges $\iff$ an $a-b$ separator has size at least $k$.

I’ve tried to recreate a proof I have learned from memory, and I’m wondering if how I’ve set it out here is valid, or if there’s something important I’m missing like an important edge case. In my proof, I’m trying to faff about less with symbols and technicalities than what has been given in my notes, which is why I’m having a bit of a hard time comparing the two.
There are a few things which make me skeptical of my proof which I will detail after having given it to you.

My proof:
The $\implies$ direction is trivial - if there are $k$ independent $a$-$b$ paths, any $a-b$ separator $S$ would have to contain some vertex within each of those paths not equal to $a$ or $b$ in order for $G-S$ to be disconnected, hence contains $k$ vertices.
The $\impliedby$ direction: suppose we take a minimal counterexample, i.e. a counterexample with minimal $|G|$, then a minimal $k$.
Suppose $S$ is an $a-b$ separator, thus $|S| = k$.
Case 1: Suppose $S \neq \Gamma(a), S \neq \Gamma(b)$, where $\Gamma(x)$ denotes the neighbourhood of $x$.
Consider the component of $G - S$ containing $b$, and form a new graph $G’$ made of all the vertices in the component of $G-S$ containing $a$, and a single vertex $b’$. $xb’$ is an edge, for $x \neq b’$, if and only if $x$ is connected to something in the component of $G-S$ containing $b$.
Then $S$ is a separator of size $k$ in $G’$, and by minimality, Menger holds in this graph $G’$. We thus require there to be $k$ edges $P_1, \dots, P_k$ from $a$ to $b’$ in $G’$.
Do a similar thing but the other way round, forming a vertex $a’$, and finding edges $Q_1, \dots, Q_k$.
Since $S$ is a separator, the $P_i$ and $Q_j$ must travel through $S$ and hence must pairwise meet at some vertex in $S$. That is, we can join up $P_i$ to $Q_j$ somehow, which form $k$ independent paths from $a$ to $b$, and hence we are done.
Case 2: Suppose any separator $S$ in $G$ has $S = \Gamma(a)$ or $S = \Gamma(b)$.
Take some path $a x_1 x_2 \dots x_n b$ from $a$ to $b$ in $G$.
Then $G’ = G - \{ x_1, x_2 \}$ is a smaller graph with one fewer path from $a$ to $b$. By minimality of $G$ as a counterexample, it thus has any $a-b$ separator $T$ with size $|T|$, which is at least the number of $a-b$ paths in $G’$.
Then $T \cup \{ x_1 \}$ and $T \cup \{ x_2 \}$ are separators in $G$.
Thus $\Gamma(a)$ and $\Gamma(b)$ are not disjoint, as we require $T \cup \{ x_1 \} = \Gamma(a)$, $T \cup \{ x_2 \} = \Gamma(b)$.
But then take $x \in \Gamma(a) \cap \Gamma(b)$. $G’’ = G - x$ will have Menger hold, i.e. any separator $S$ has size at least $k-1$, where $k$ is defined to be the number of $a-b$ paths in $G’’$ plus one.
But then any separator in $G$ will have to be of the form $S \cup \{ x \}$ for $S$ a separator in $G’’$. $G’’$ has $|S| \geq k-1$ independent $a-b$ paths, $G$ has $k$ as we have the extra path $axb$. But then $|S \cup \{ x \}| \geq k$, so $G$ satisfies Menger. This contradicts it being a minimal counterexample. Q.E.D.

I’m particularly unsure of

why we need minimal $k$ as well as minimal $|G|$, where is that used in the proof?

In case $1$, whether the argument showing the existence of the paths $P_i$, $Q_j$ is valid, or if more needs to be said. What if the component $b$ is in within $G - S$ is of size $1$ anyway, then shrinking the component down to $b’$ surely has not changed the graph, so how can we use the minimality of $G$ as an argument here?


If anything else in my proof can be critiqued and improved upon, please inform me of that also.

One thing that confuses me is the seeming usage of edge and path interchangeably: normally a path can be comprised of many edges.
You use the minimality of $k$ in case 2, on $G'$.
In case 1, you don't need to do anything if one side of $G-S$ is a single vertex, you already have the paths to $S$ you need, namely the edges. This is not using minimality, so it would be good to make a comment along these lines.
